# NASA uses a program that takes their black and photos turned into color using a shade of gray for one particular

Tags: colors, gimp, grayscale

I have a a black & photo and I want to convert the *shades of gray* into individual colors. For example a storm cloud with all different shades of gray, I want to assign a shade of gray to one color or a range of grays to a set of colors

Comment: You might be more likely to get an answer at https://photo.stackexchange.com/